# Throw exception from Listener

Tags: android, asynchronous, exception, listener

I'm replacing a sync method for an async one doing the same job. The old method was throwing a custom exception if something went wrong. Now I've got a listener in the new method and I don't know how to keep throwing that exception:

```
@Override
protected void methodBeingChanged() throws customException {

    asyncMethod(new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response, int responseCode) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(IOException e) {
        }
    });

}
```

This exception is later being catch by another method in another class which gives feedback to the user depending on the exception message.

Comment: you don't throw the error just notify that an error occurred to your listener. You will have to rewrite the part of the code that was handling the exception and instead deal with notification from listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible. Your async task is run on another thread and your current `methodBeingChanged` is finish right away, which means the exception is never  thrown by `methodBeingChanged`.

The only solution is modify the caller code, add another listener method for the specific exception

Answer (score 0):

This may sound silly, but just throw it :p

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html

```
@Override
protected void methodBeingChanged() throws customException {

    asyncMethod(new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response, int responseCode) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {
            try {
                throw new customException ();
            }catch(customException cEx) {
                // Do stuff
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It gives me the error "unhandled exception" and suggest to surround it with a "try, catch".

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer. You can simply catch it as well. Since you just mentioned throwing the exception, I thought you only wanted to throw it to be caught somewhere else. But this way you can catch it easily.

Comment: Yeah but that way is not catched by the "methodBeingChanged", something that now I understand is impossible (Tam answer).